# How to send variable to url, get input, then print results java

Tags: java, eclipse, http, url, ip

I am trying to send a variable (IP address) in java to a website (whois.com) and have the variable be entered into the websites search bar then print out the results in my program.

Comment: only if they provide any API for it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to study the website, look at the form to find out what request (POST, GET, fields, etc.) is expects, then send that request and parse the result. In other words, you have to simulate being a browser. Not something you should do.

https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/ offers a real API, perhaps that's something for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give *hostname* to getByName() method and it returns

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/helo");
System.out.println(url.getHost());
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
System.out.println(address.toString());
```

The output will be :

> www.engineering.uiowa.edu/111.111.111.111

To get the raw ip :

```
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
```